# How can I create a struct with a vTable or array of function pointers in C?

Tags: c

I am having a problem with declaring a struct with an array of function pointers (vTable) in C because if I declare the function pointer first **and a parameter needs to be a self-referencial "this" pointer to itself**, the struct hasn't yet been declared. If I declare the function pointer AFTER the struct, then the function type hasn't been declared so the compiler complains when I set up the struct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef int (*math_operation) (struct _MyClass *this,int a, int b);
typedef struct _MyClass{
    int number;
    char name[50];
    math_operation *vTable[50];
} MyClass;
int main(void)
{
    MyClass *test;
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

What is the proper way to create an array of function pointer which have a "this" pointer to the parent struct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need a forward declaration of the struct in the global namespace:

```
struct MyClass_; 
typedef int math_operation(struct MyClass_ *this, int a, int b);

typedef struct MyClass_{
    int number;
    char name[50];
    math_operation *vTable[50];
} MyClass;
```

Things to note:

1. I fixed the tag identifier, so it won't tread on the [C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3).
2. I changed the function *pointer* typedef into a function *type* typedef. You already defined `vTable` as an array of pointers to `math_operation`. One pointer declarator was superfluous. This also has the nice utility of allowing you to declare functions by their intended purpose, and have the compiler type check it:

   ```
   math_operation add;

   // .. Later

   int add(struct MyClass_ *this, int a, int b) {
     return a + b;
   }
   ```